# PHP SSH2 скорость работы

Tags: php, оптимизация, ssh

Здравствуйте!
Есть такой скрипт на php:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000);
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 1);
$ips=file("ip.txt");
function ssh_exec($n) {
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
if(!(@$con = ssh2_connect($n, 22))){
    echo $n." - fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {
   if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "user", "pass")) {
        echo $n." - fail: unable to authenticate\n";
    } else {
        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "cat version" ))) {
            echo $n." - fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } else {
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $data = "";
            while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                $data .= $buf;
            }
            if (!$data = 'version.1') {
            echo $n." - ".$data;} else {echo $n." - ok\n";}
            fclose($stream);
        }
    }
}
}
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($ips as $ip => $n) {
ssh_exec(trim($n));
}
echo "</pre>";
echo "Time:  " . number_format(( microtime(true) - $startTime), 4) . " Seconds\n";
```

На одно соединение уходит 1.3 секунды, проблема в том, что айпишников 600+ и чтобы опросить все устройства надо примерно минут 13-15.
Возможно ли оптимизировать этот процесс/скрипт? SNMP не вариант пока.

Comment: вы сами ставите stream_set_blocking, когда, очевидно, можно обрабатывать штук по тридцать в неблокирующем режиме

Comment: c stream_set_blocking($stream, 0) разница в 1 секунду при 20 ip

Comment: а я не про то, чтобы одну строчку сменить.

Answer (score 1):

Если из под браузера то можно распаралелить , отправив операцию конекта и проверки в отдельную нитку если по простому то можно юзать `pcntl_fork();` если есть доступ к shell то можно как то так:

```
seq 600| parallel php your_script.php {} > log_check_ssh{}
```

Тоесть запустить ваш скрипт 600 раз где {} порядковый номер вашего соединения из массива соединений а в скрипте считывать этот номер через `$argv[1]` , так вы паралельно выполните 600 проверок и сохраните каждую проверку в лог с именем `log_check_ssh{}`.